Unit test for HttpGraphQlClient in spring boot 3 and java 17 with Mockito and Junit?
hi I am using HttpGraphQlClient from package spring-boot-starter-graphql in spring boot 3 with java 17. Now i am stuck with writing the unit test cases for the method.
Considering that I have proper configuration for the dependency and api is working in method call.
*In my service- *
public void callApi(){
   var response = httpGraphQlClient.document("test").retrieve("pokemon").toEntity(List.class).block();
}

I tried using the RestAssured but that doesn't seem to be working.

For unit test we can mock all interactions with other parts. Let's start with mocking HttpGraphQlClient. First we should think how we will use our mock. For that we can inject it into service. Our service might be
@Service
public class PockemonService {

    // injected variable defined in constructor
    private HttpGraphQlClient httpGraphQlClient;

    @Autowired
    public PockemonService(HttpGraphQlClient httpGraphQlClient) {
        this.httpGraphQlClient = httpGraphQlClient;
    }

    public List<String> callApi() {
        return httpGraphQlClient // we shall mock it in unit test
                                 .document("test") // returns RequestSpec, mock it too
                                 .retrieve("pockemon") // returns RetrievSpec, also mock it
                                 .toEntity(List.class)
                                 .block();
    }
}

Now we can test our API starting with mocking HttpGraphQlClient and mocking all it's methods used in API
public class PockemonServiceTest {

    @Test
    void callApi() {
        // expected result
        List<String> expected = List.of("pockemon1", "pockemon2");
        // mock RequestSpec
        GraphQlClient.RequestSpec requestSpec = Mockito.mock(GraphQlClient.RequestSpec.class);
        // mock RetriveSpec
        GraphQlClient.RetrieveSpec retrieveSpec = Mockito.mock(GraphQlClient.RetrieveSpec.class);

        // mock HttpGraphQlClient
        HttpGraphQlClient httpGraphQlClient = Mockito.mock(HttpGraphQlClient.class);
        // define mock results
        doReturn(requestSpec).when(httpGraphQlClient).documentName(anyString());
        doReturn(retrieveSpec).when(requestSpec).retrieve(anyString());
        doReturn(Mono.just(expected)).when(retrieveSpec).toEntity(List.class);
        // inject mocked httpGraphQlClient into service
        PockemonService pockemonService = new PockemonService(httpGraphQlClient);
        // execute service method
        List<String> actual = pockemonService.callApi();

        // verify result
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

}

RestAssure typically used in integration tests. Considering integration tests is out of scope this answer

@mmishra In such case please accept the answer ))
